# An upper bound of the sum $\sum_{n\le X}n^{k-2}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $k$ be an integer $\ge 5,$ I'm concerned with finding an upper bound of the following sum:
$$\sum_{n\le X}n^{k-2}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the sum start at $n = 0$ or some other value?

Comment: @JimmyK4542,  Yes the sum star at $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way to bound that summation. $$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{X}n^{k-2} \le \sum_{n = 0}^{X}\int_{n}^{n+1}x^{k-2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{X+1}x^{k-2}\,dx = \dfrac{1}{k-1}(X+1)^{k-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm interested in a bound like: $\ll_k X^\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0 $ with $\varepsilon$  independent of $k$

Comment: @user1456783 The order of magnitude of the sum is $\asymp X^{k-1}$, so the bound you are requesting cannot be true.

Comment: @Kyle, Thanks for your comment, could you please explain to me how did you find that $\sum_{n\le X}n^{k-2}\asymp X^{k-1}$

Comment: The upper bound was given by Jimmy. For the lower bound, note that $\sum_{X/2 < n \leq X} n^{k-2} \gg X^{k-1}$.

Comment: @Kyle, Thanks for your comment, I don't see how you obtain this lower bound $\sum_{X/2<n\le X}n^{k-2}$, I' think we must use "dyadic summation" to get $\sum_{n\le X}n^{k-2}\gg X^{k-1},$ Could you please give me a reference in which I can read about it.

Comment: @Kyle, I want a reference to learn this technique of "dyadic summation".

Comment: @user1456783 A good place to start might be the following: http://www.tricki.org/article/Dyadic_decomposition